# What is the difference between these two ways of unordered_map declaration?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

What is the difference between below two ways of declarations?

```
unordered_map<int, int> mp;

auto umap = unordered_map<int, int>{};
```

Is there something to do with optimization?

Comment: Your second line doesn’t compile. (And which fix you’d make to make it compile is *very* relevant to the question.)

Comment: @Sneftel I missed to include "{ }".

Comment: FYI: [Diff on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/x9fzeE5qT)

Comment: @AdrianMole pls check now. I missed to include "{ }".

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/8nn4fw/forrest_gump_learns_c/

Comment: Since C++17, *"mandatory copy-elision"* make both sample equivalent. pre-c++17, up to compiler to avoid the extra move.

Answer (score 4):

For an `unordered_map` it won't make a difference since c++17.

It will make a difference if the type is e.g. an aggregate type.

So if you have and `std::array`, there would be a different outcome for:

```
std::array<int, 4> a1;

auto a2 = std::array<int, 4>{};
```

`a1` will contain indeterminate values.

On the other hand, those would be equal:

```
std::array<int, 4> a1{};

auto a2 = std::array<int, 4>{};
```

So using  `auto var = some_type{};` (which is also referred to as "almost always auto pattern") would ensure that you don't forget to initialize a variable.